# Error 500 when deleting lots of products

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento 1.4.0.1

I'm trying to delete products based on their sku. I searched in the product manager and have found and selected the ~9000 products which must be deleted.

When I try to delete them it hangs for a bit then gives me error 500. None of them get deleted.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in **php configuration** (php.ini) increase **memory_limit** to at least **128M** (256M is better with Magento) and set **max_execution_time** to a higher value (expressed in seconds) until you get your job done.

Hope it helps.

Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

500 error is shown in your php error log. Most probably you are running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete products via direct SQL query as described in this wiki entry: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/import-export_and_data_manipulation/removing_products_through_the_database
Just not sure that works correctly in current Magento versions

Comment: I need to match SKU on a regular expression